# Get custom phtml content using observer on core_block_abstract_to_html_after event

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a custom block that I would like to append under a existing core block in the order view page in the admin panel of Magento.

I developed my custom module.

In order to avoid modification of a core template phtml file to load my custom block, I try to follow the best practices and I built an observer on the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after`

if you want to know why Read more two excellent articles above

http://www.atwix.com/magento/best-practices/

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-you-could-build-your-magento-extensions-without-view-files/

However while the block, that I want to append, will contain lots of html I want to put this html in a custom phtml file and not directly in the php, to make it more easily customizable for designers.

I created so a phtm file in the following folder

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\custommodulefolder\customhtmlfileforadminorderview.phtml
```

But how to load this phtml content from the observer ?

```
<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <custommodule>
                        <class>NameSpace_CustomModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>RenderBlockCustomdAdmin</method>
                    </referencefield>
                </custommodule>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
```

And the method in my `Observer.php`

```
    public function RenderBlockCustomdAdmin($observer = NULL)
        {
            if (!$observer) {
                return;
            }

            if ('order_info' == $observer->getEvent()->getBlock()->getNameInLayout()) {

                if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/'.self::MODULE_NAME)) {

                    $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();

// here I would like to find a way to load the content of a custom of phtml
                    $htmfromablock= function_which_will_allow-me_to_get_content_phtmlfile() 
                    $transportOldHtml =$transport->getHtml();
                    $transport->setHtml($transportOldHtml.'<br />'.$htmfromablock);
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }
```

Comment: Why you just can't add block in layout?

Comment: thanks for your input, i did not do that because it would mean to modify app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml by inserting an echo of the block in the layout. Therefore it's not generic, when someone install mymodule if this file had already some modifications and it can conflict, etc..

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure your module output is not disabled? Also, is the constant self::MODULE_NAME defined for your observer?

Comment: Thanks David, but benoit answered to my issues. Thanks all for your help and different inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a block is fairly easy when you get the layout (it is just a matter of calling `createBlock()` with the block type you want and `setTemplate()` with the template you want to use).
And you can always get the layout from another block.

So in your case :

```
$observer->getEvent()
         ->getBlock()
         ->getLayout()
         ->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
         ->setTemplate('custommodulefolder/customhtmlfileforadminorderview.phtml')
         ->toHtml();
```

Comment: thanks a lot b.enoit.be make the whole stuff much more clear. I had my custom block I replaced ->createBlock('adminhtml/template') with ->createBlock('blocklayoutdeclaration/customblock') like this I can have all my methods available with $this. Thanks again, really helped. Magento architecture even if it can be simple can be as well very complex .